# laravel 5.5 built in authentication database table reference location

Tags: database, laravel, authentication, built-in

I have a problem with using Laravel built in authentication feature. As a default Laravel authentication access `users` table to check/add username and password. I need to change it to `student` table. normally in a model `protected $table=student` code is used to mention which table to use.

Can anyone tell me where the `protected $table=` code or similar is found within the built in authentication feature?

Part 2
The code below is the code in my controller where I take the form data into `$data` and validating and returning it into my store function, but I get an error

> Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::store(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

```
protected function validator(array $data)
 {
   $data = Request::all();
     return Validator::make($data, [
         'fname' => 'required|string|max:255',
         'lname' => 'required|string|max:255',
         'district' => 'required|string|max:255',
         'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:student',
         'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
     ]);`
 }

public function store(array $data)
{
  return Student::create([
      'fname' => $data['fname'],
      'lname' => $data['lname'],
      'district' => $data['district'],
      'email' => $data['email'],
      'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add**:

```
protected $table=student;
```

to `User` model at `app/User.php`

and

In `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`,

**Change**:

```
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
```

**To**:

```
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:student',
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. could you be more specific please. when you mentioned AuthController, is it Controllers->Auth->LoginController.php. or is there a different controller named AuthController.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in the App\User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = "users_old"; //your custom table

    ....
}
```